# ClienteApiRestService suscribe in angular paralell?

Tags: angular

I have a CRUD,
and when I set the value of a field, I must first update the field, and then bring me all the fields.

If I do the operation in two ".subscribe" both requests are executed "in parallel" and the crud is not updated correctly.
(We would update the crud without even having set the field even though the instruction is behind)

```
 this.clienteApiRest.putEnabled(this.enableSelector,
 !this.enabled).subscribe(res => {
       this.clienteApiRest.getAllUsers(this.enabled).subscribe(
         (resp: User[]) => {
           this.users = resp; //asigna la responsive de users hacia la Users [] local que teniamos.
           console.log("datos: " + resp);
           resp.forEach(function (data) {
           });
         },
         err => console.log("Error: " + err)
       );
     }
  );
```

If I include the ".subscribe" to get the users of the crud inside the subscribe to modify it, then the request is correct.

```
 this.clienteApiRest.putEnabled(this.enableSelector, !this.enabled).subscribe(res => {})
 **parallel execution?** 
 this.clienteApiRest.getAllUsers(this.enabled).subscribe(
        (resp: User[]) => {
          this.users = resp; //asigna la responsive de users hacia la Users [] local que teniamos.
          console.log("datos: " + resp);
          resp.forEach(function (data) {
          });
        },
        err => console.log("Error: " + err)
      );
      }
    );
```

**Why does this happen?**

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly, it might help to know that you're experiencing revelation on asynchronus programming. JS is asynchornus which would mean your subscribe blocks are going to be **called back** when they are done. It might help to research a bit about async code execution, if you really want to get into it research the node event loop

Comment: Your real issue here is bad API design - but besides that, you’d really want to read up on RxJs. Nesting subscriptions is a bad idea, this can be easily fixed with a switchMap or similar operator.

Answer (score 1):

The Angular documentation does a good job explaining this.

Your code uses **Observables** - anything you can do `.subscribe()` to.

https://angular.io/guide/observables

TLDR; observables execute code asynchronously by design to allow your application to carry on running other tasks. For example, for calling APIs.